# Python giving illegal instruction(core dumped) error when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using arch linux and installed tensorflow via pip

```
>>> import tensorflow
[New Thread 0x7ffff29ec700 (LWP 1500)]

Thread 1 "python" received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00007fffe7e93880 in std::pair<std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<tensorflow::StringPiece const, std::function<bool (tensorflow::Variant*)> >, false, true>, bool> std::_Hashtable<tensorflow::StringPiece, std::pair<tensorflow::StringPiece const, std::function<bool (tensorflow::Variant*)> >, std::allocator<std::pair<tensorflow::StringPiece const, std::function<bool (tensorflow::Variant*)> > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<tensorflow::StringPiece>, tensorflow::StringPieceHasher, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_M_emplace<std::pair<tensorflow::StringPiece, std::function<bool (tensorflow::Variant*)> > >(std::integral_constant<bool, true>, std::pair<tensorflow::StringPiece, std::function<bool (tensorflow::Variant*)> >&&) ()
   from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so
(gdb) bt
\0  0x00007fffe7e93880 in std::pair<std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<tensorflow::StringPiece const, std::function<bool (tensorflow::Variant*)> >, false, true>, bool> std::_Hashtable<tensorflow::StringPiece, std::pair<tensorflow::StringPiece const, std::function<bool (tensorflow::Variant*)> >, std::allocator<std::pair<tensorflow::StringPiece const, std::function<bool (tensorflow::Variant*)> > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<tensorflow::StringPiece>, tensorflow::StringPieceHasher, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_M_emplace<std::pair<tensorflow::StringPiece, std::function<bool (tensorflow::Variant*)> > >(std::integral_constant<bool, true>, std::pair<tensorflow::StringPiece, std::function<bool (tensorflow::Variant*)> >&&) ()
   from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so
```

Comment: You should probably tell us what OS you're using (and maybe its version), and where you got Python and tensorflow from, if they aren't a standard part of the OS.

Comment: You probably have a tensorflow library optimized for a different CPU than yours CPU (think about all vector extensions on x86 CPUs). Recompule tensorflow or get a "slower" version.

Comment: I am running arch linux and installed tensorflow via pip. Version of python is 3.6.4 @Blckknght

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your pip tensorflow package.

```
sudo pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Try installing the official [tensorflow](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/tensorflow/) package.

```
sudo pacman -S tensorflow python-tensorflow
```

Later, you can try [tensorflow-cuda](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/tensorflow-cuda/) and [python-tensorflow-cuda](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/python-tensorflow-cuda/).

```
sudo pacman -S tensorflow-cuda python-tensorflow-cuda
```